# SQL Server reset numbers

Tags: sql, vb.net

am using SQL Server with Visual basic VB.net,am using application with Record data to sql
 [image]

SQL Server
[image]

hello , is there code i can reset those number from vb.net by button or reset by monthly
 **totalpoint** to ( 0 )
**monthlypoint** to 4

[Special**TotalPoints**] int, to > 0
[Special**MonthPoints**]int,to > 4

[rasmeTotalPoints] int,to > 0
[rasmeMonthPoints] int,to > 12

[EmergencyTotalPoints] int,to > 0
[EmergencyMonthPoints] int,to > 4

if anyone could help me
thanks

Comment: What do you mean with the ">" sign in the question? It might be clearer if you edited your question to show an example of a row before and after the change, preferably as text not an image.

Comment: So, you're asking us how to execute an `UPDATE` statement against your database?

Comment: yes  jmcilhinney , monthly  or by button rest all those numbers , if monthly 4 and  using 1 point well be total 1 and monthly 3 , so i would like after 1 month or by button rest them , monthly to 4 and total to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the following statement when clicking your reset button to do what you want:

```
UPDATE
  dbo.Table_infoname
SET
  [SpecialTotalPoints] = 0,
  [SpecialMonthPoints] = 4,
  [rasmeTotalPoints] = 0,
  [rasmeMonthPoints] = 12
  [EmergencyTotalPoints] = 0,
  [EmergencyMonthPoints] = 4
```

Be careful as this will update all rows in your table. You probably want to limit the `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks got it now must be like this : UPDATE [dbo].[Table_infoname] SET [SpecialTotalPoints] = 0